# Can bibtex fields be referenced like variables?

Tags: bibtex

Can I revise the following bibtex entry to avoid duplicating the author's name, without defining a @string?

```
@misc{key,
    author = "Joe Blogs",
    title = "Title",
    year = "2014",
    note = "Joe Blogs ...."
}
```

I know I can do the following:

```
@string { Blogs = "Joe Blogs" } 

@misc{key,
    author = Blogs,
    title = "Title",
    year = "2014",
    note = Blogs # " ...."
}
```

But this seems like overkill, because I have to define Blogs using @string.

Given that I have already defined "Joe Blogs" as the author field of "key", can I somehow reference the existing value?

**UPDATE.** I'm looking for 'standard' solutions, i.e., solutions which work with the [bibtex](http://www.bibtex.org/) tool, so LaTeX solutions are interesting, but no use to me. (I'm not actually using  the bibtex tool, I'm using a PHP bibtex parser. But this is largely irrelevant for the purposes of this question, since the PHP bibtex parser I'm using is designed to the same specification as the  bibtex tool.)

**Answer.** The answer appears to be **no**: bibtex fields *cannot* be referenced like variables.

Comment: Not with BibTeX, but maybe with [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Comment: In general, no; but maybe [CrossTeX](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/egs/crosstex/) will be of interest to you. (Note: last update on seems to be from 2008.)

Comment: I'm using the bibtex file in combination with [http://www.monperrus.net/martin/bibtexbrowser/], so I don't have the option to use biblatex nor CrossTeX.

Comment: @user2768: So what is the output of BibTeXBrowser? A `.bib` or a `.bbl`? It seems like the output is a `.bib`. If that's the case, why can't you use `biblatex`?

Comment: @Werner, bibtexbrowser inputs a bib file and spits out HTML, e.g., http://www.astro.gla.ac.uk/?page_id=865

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a parser which while it reads BibTeX isn't used in a TeX tool-chain.

Comment: As it stands, this seems to be off-topic. If you are using a parser that is PHP-based, then it's not really 'TeX like' but just a question of the type of database formate you've got. Presumably you could simply modify you parser to do what you want. If on the other hand the question is about 'standard' BibTeX (_i.e._ how BibTeX-the-program parses files) then the question should be edited to make that clear.

Comment: @JosephWright, I'm unconvinced that this is off-topic:  the question is about 'standard' BibTeX. If bibtex fields could be referenced like variables, then all bibtex parsers (including PHP parsers and those in the TeX tool-chain) should parse correctly. It is true that the PHP parser I am using can be modified to do what I want, but equally, I could modify the TeX tool-chain; this isn't a 'standard' solution.

Comment: @user2768 OK, I'll re-open. Could you edit to make it clear that you are interested in the 'standard' behaviour as defined by BibTeX-the-program?

Comment: @JosephWright, done.

Answer (score 6):

Not with BibTeX alone.

If you're using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) you can:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{A1,
   author = {Author One},
   title = {Alpha},
   publisher = {Publisher A},
   year = {2000},
   }

@BOOK{B2,
   author = {Author Two},
   title = {Beta},
   publisher = {Publisher B},
   year = {2001},
   }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeAuthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{author}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{\jobname}
\begin{document}

Author of \cite{A1} is \citeauthor{A1} (\citeAuthor{A1}) in \citeyear{A1}.
Author of \cite{B2} is \citeauthor{B2} (\citeAuthor{B2}) in \citeyear{B2}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sure this solution works, but I was looking for a "pure" bibtex solution.